Change of Bluetooth address or connection type of Bluetooth on Android by code
Is there a way by code to change Bluetooth settings on Android?
For example, change whether I have an earphone connection on my device, change the address or connection type from a car headset to an earpiece
I don't know if there is such a possibility, I would love help
